# How to include arguments in a where-clause in Android SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table T1, which has a float column representing the julianday. Now I want to delete the entries which julianday is older than n-day. I tried:

```
db.delete(T1, COL_JULIANDAY + " <= julianday('now', '- ? days')",
  new String[] { Integer.toString(days) });
```

But I got an error from Android:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range
```

I think it is because the '?' mark is quoted in my where-clause.

Comment: what are you trying to delete ? this is correct syntax db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs)

Comment: yes, the syntax is correct. but API cannot recognize the '?' mark in the quotes. it treats the '?' mark in my code as a literal '?' mark...

Comment: have you tried lalit's code ?

Comment: I am sure Lalit's code will work. But here I am looking for a way to work with the built-in API. If it is not achievable, I will resort to raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than resorting to raw SQL, I suggest trying to use concatenation operators in your where clause.

```
db.delete(T1, COL_JULIANDAY + " <= julianday('now', '- ' || ? || ' days')",
    new String[] { Integer.toString(days) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it yet but this is how I think it should be,

```
db.delete(T1, COL_JULIANDAY + " <= julianday(?)", new String[] 
                                                    { Integer.toString(days) });
```

If you prefer you can simply use sql query with `db.execSQL(statement);`

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+T1+" where COL_JULIANDAY <= julianday('"+days+"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
julianday('now', '- ? days')
```

should be the same as

```
julianday('now') - ?
```

Comment: I guess I am lucky in this case. But what if I want julianday('now', '-? months')?